# How to use php readfile() across partitions?

Tags: php, partition, arch-linux

[I've been struggling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623852/permission-issue-when-using-readfile) to get PHP readfile() to work properly. After drilling down all options, it turns out that I can not get this to work when I am trying to open a file that is located on another partition. My webroot folder is located under the root partition (`/webroot`), and I want to access files located under `/home`.

- Permissions are just fine
- open_basedir is deactivated
- If I move the same folder and files to a folder under `/`, then it all works, but if it's located under `/home`, then it does not work anymore. Permissions are 777 and owner of the folder is Apache, so it is really not a file permission issue.

Here's my fstab:

```
# /dev/sda1
UUID=...    /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1

# /dev/sda6
UUID=...    /home       ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 2
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Warning: readfile(/home/files/1.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /webroot/download.php
```

I'm not finding any partition-related limitations in the documentation. My logfiles do not indicate any particular error either. I do not have selinux installed.

EDIT: open_basedir is NOT at fault. I have checked this thoroughly. Both by specifically including the folder that is at stake, and by commenting out the whole open_basedir directive. Also, if I do force an open_basedir error, then the actual error message is different.

Current open_basedir setting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXe7T.png

Using Arch Linux, PHP 5.4.13

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: short answer, check the value of php's [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) directive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure open_basedir's message says that it is open_basedir's fault, though maybe it can be turned off to just give a generic permission denied error.  I'm thinking SELinux personally, but I don't know if archlinux uses a variable to enable/disable httpd access to /home

Comment: @forcefsck thanks, but open_basedir is not the issue, unfortunately. I have added more info to my post.

Comment: @DerfK thanks, but I do not have SELinux running on my box.

Comment: When do you say "I do not have selinux installed", what do you mean? What's the output of "sestatus"?

Comment: @mricon I mean that I did not install the packages for selinux. `sestatus` returns `sestatus: command not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet a large sum of money on the fact that the partition the file is located on has *nothing* to do with why you can't open it (as long as the filesystem is mounted).

> Permissions are 777 and owner of the folder is Apache, so it is really not a file permission issue.

But PHP is explicitly telling you that it's a permissions problem:

> failed to open stream: Permission denied

If you've ruled out open_basedir and selinux, then other things to check:

1) is PHP running as the apache uid? That's OK if it's mod_php but for php-fpm, that's messy.

2) is the PHP running in a chroot jail?

3) What do you get from:

```
<?php

function show_p($path)
{
   print "path=" . $path . "n";
   print "permissions=" . substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($path)), -4) . "\n";
   print_r(stat($path))
}
print "uid=" . getmyuid() . "\n";
print "gid=" . getmygid() . "\n";
show_p('/home');
show_p('/home/files');
show_p('/home/files/1.txt');
print "acl=" . `getfacl -1 /home/files/1.txt` . "\n";
```

Comment: THANK YOU! 1 & 2) PHP is running as Apache, and not in chroot, but your 3rd suggestion did the trick. /home/ had `700` permission, which is why PHP could not access the folder or files below, despite their permissions. Thanks!